# Save entity with java.time.Instant property using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate with postgres driver

Tags: postgresql, spring-jdbc

I am having issues saving my entity that has a Instant value using the NamedJdbcTemplate. I receive the exception listed below and I am trying to determine the best way to resolve this. Please advise.

> Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of java.time.Instant. Use setObject() with an explicit Types value to specify the type to use.

I am using the `postgresql:9.4.1212` driver

Comment: I am able to save entities that have LocalDate and LocalDateTime properties but not Instant. Can someone explain why this is still not supported in the JDBC driver?

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated driver? Did you try with a more recent version?

Comment: This is the driver our prod environment uses and I must use this version. I tried the latest of this driver and it still has the issue. All other Types in the java.time.* api work without issue but for some reason the driver doesn't support instant

Comment: What is the data type of the column? I can't think of any Postgres type that would map to a `java.tiime.Instant`. Why not use `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: I have tried a timestamp column with and without timezone. Should probably actually try a big int. Don't want to use those types as they carry inherent knowledge of timezones and I would like to avoid anything relating to timezones and let each app use the timezone it needs as the Instant will be represented as UTC. I guess I could create localDateTime's and convert but would like to avoid that as it gets tricky in some edge cases

Comment: Then use a `LocalDateTime` that does not carry any timezone information. Passing that through `setObject()` works for me - at least with the most recent driver version, not sure if that old version supports that.

Comment: localdatetime inherently doesn't carry the timezone info. it just creates a date in the system default timezone which is going to be an inaccurate time when read in other TZ.

Comment: The convert the LocalDateTime to a value in UTC before saving

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
Instant ts = // whatever instant
MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
params.addValue("ts", Timestamp.from(ts), Types.TIMESTAMP);

jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL, params)
```

where SQL is the parametrized query and make sure you're using java.sql.Timestamp and java.sql.Types.